# Compare size of 2 Arrays in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, size

If I have 2 arrays, how do I compare them and return the size of the smallest one? Here is what I mean:

```
val a = Array(1,2,3)
val b = Array(1,2,3,4)
```

is there some operator that I could call to compare the sizes of both and return 3, since Array a is smaller and has 3 elements?

Answer (score 3):

```
scala> val a = Array(1,2,3)
a: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)

scala> val b = Array(1,2,3,4)
b: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> math.min(a.length, b.length)
res0: Int = 3
```

Comment: I figured it out and used:
if (a.size > b.size) b.size else a.size
which works as well, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val a = Array(1,2,3)
a:Array[Int] = Array(1,2,3)

scala> val b = Array(1,2,3,4)
b:Array[Int] = Array(1,2,3,4)

scala> a.size min b.size
res0: Int = 3
```

The size method gets the size of the Array and `min` is a comparator function between the two sizes. As with any function taking two parameters, you can call it by putting the function name between the parameters.

`min` is doing an implicit conversion (a set of methods that Scala tries to apply when it encounters an object of the wrong type being used) from `Int` to `RichInt`.

Comment: You may want to emphasize the fact that min method comes from [implicit conversion](http://take.ms/IEYWIE) from Int to [RichInt](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.runtime.RichInt)

Comment: Please note, that min is not an operator, but a function, taking two parameters. You can call it by putting the functionname between the parameters. This works for all functions wich are taking two parameters.

Comment: Thank you. I have adjusted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A more generic approach, assuming you want to compare Sequences of the same type.

```
 def getSmallerCollectionSize[T](a:Seq[T],b:Seq[T]) =
      Math.min(a.size, b.size)
```

Comment: As it is now it is very low quality. Please add some explanation to improve your answer and make it useful also for the future readers, not only for the OP.